# Can I do a query that has both distinct and non distinct fields in it?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a link field that I would like to query and get all the unique links. I would also like to get the name fields, in which two links could have the same name. Is there a way to do a query that would get one field as distinct and the remaining fields as non distinct?

Comment: By SQL do you mean *MS SQL Server*, or just generic ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work too:

```
SELECT name, link
FROM table
GROUP BY name, link
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `unique_field`, `other_field` FROM `table`.
```